# Need help to split string in java

Tags: java, string

Please help me to split string like this "mumbai (or) pune" using java.

I want the string after ")", I tried using `string.split()` but not working on above String format.

my expected output is "pune".

input:

```
String abc="mumbai (or) pune"
```

output:

```
String result="pune".
```

Comment: Provide some sample input and output.

Answer (score 1):

If your input string is always similar to the one you showed:

```
yourString.split("\\)")[1].trim();
```

Comment: You should check the length before trying to access `1`

Comment: yeah, but i assume that the string will containg `)` char ;)

Comment: can u please explain why u have used .get(1).trim();

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't work because `)` is special in regex. Escape the regex with `\\`.

Use `string.split("\\)")[1].trim();` instead.

Answer (score 1):

You can split it into parts:

```
String abc="mumbai (or) pune"
String result = "pune";

String[] parts = abc.split(" ");
String partOne = parts[0];
String partTwo = parts[2];

if (partOne == result){
   System.out.println(partOne);
}
else{
   System.out.println(partTwo);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
String s = "mumbai (or) pune";
String result = s.substring(s.lastIndexOf(')') + 1).trim();
```

Answer (score 0):

A replace would be actually more efficient here.

Use :

```
 String abc="mumbai (or) pune";
 abc = abc.replaceAll(".*\\s+(\\w+)","$1");
 // abc will be "pune" here
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do the simple thing which you are looking for. Best approach: Read of String Operations in Java

Following are just some ways to achieve what you need:

```
 public static void main(String[] args)
{
    String output1 = "mumbai (or) pune";
    String output2 = output1.split("or\\) ")[1];
    String output3 = output1.substring(output1.indexOf(")")+2);;        

    System.out.println(output1);
    System.out.println(output2);
    System.out.println(output3);        
}
```